# How to create a Git GUI and parse git's output?

Tags: git, user-interface, console, exec

I want to create a little Git GUI and my idea is to make a program that calls the normal git software (using `exec` or something similar), but my problem is that I don't know what to do with the `stdout` (output) of git. It prints everything as a string.

Is there a way to make it print some kind of data that can be easily parsed, such as a JSON or something?

How are GUIs like git-gui for Windows or Gitkraken getting the output?

If you know another program that works like that, then please tell me the approach I can use.

Comment: You could use `git <command> --porcelain` to get more machine-readable output. For example, If you ran `git status` on a repo with no changes, you would get some unnecessary info, like a prompt to push for example. But if you ran `git status --porcelain`, there would be zero output

Answer (score 3):

There are libraries for working with git in many languages. For example, you can use python's [gitpython](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) or ruby's [ruby-git](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git), etc.

For example:

```
from git import Repo
repo = Repo("/path/to/a/repo")
for file in repo.untracked_files:
    print("untracked file:", file)
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got 2 possibilities with their own advantages and trade offs.

1. Use the git exe

Pro:

- Up to date
- do not behave differently than the official client, contrary to a library (major advantage)

Cons:

- painful to use and parse output
- need to support different versions

But some commands could output something easier to parse. See for example parameters `--porcelain` or `--output`in the command help:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status

2. Use a library in your language of choice.

You could try to use a pure implementation in your language of choice or use a wrapper around the well maintained library 'libgit2' https://libgit2.github.com/

Pro:

- Really easier to use
- performance could be better (no need to read git files at every command)

Cons:

- use could be a little different or features limited (especially for language pure implementations)

Ps: which language and which system do you target? Why not improve an existing GUI? Because that's a lot of hard work...